# Why does my Canon SX40 ask me to set the time every time I turn it on?

Tags: canon

I have canon sx40, I am using it for three years, from last month in the start time always it comes set time and if I skips then taken images takes 1980 as date, I can not understand what is the problem, is there any internal battery in camera, do I need to change it ?

Comment: If you can charge the battery in the camera on that model, you might be able to keep the clock powered.  That's not common on Canons though and would need a (possibly expensive) accessory charger/power supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SX40 uses a rechargeable built-in date/time battery. They are supposed to keep working for about 7 years, but it appears yours has died a little early.

It is not user replaceable.

You will need to continue setting the date each time you remove the main battery, or you could have Canon replace the date/time battery.

[Canon SX40 User Manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300005730/01/pssx40hs-cug-c-en-web.pdf)

[image]